# What is the best way of performing a string concatenation in making a dynamic URL?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am constructing a URL at runtime. So far I have done like

```
public string BuildURLAndNavigate(CodeType codeType)
{    
    string vURL = string.Empty; 

    string mstrNavServer = "http://some.com/nav";
    vURL = ConcatenateString(mstrNavServer , "/somepage.asp?app=myapp");

    //Build Code Type
    switch (codeType)
    {
    case CodeType.Series:
        vURL = ConcatenateString(vURL , "&tools=ser");
        break; 
    case CodeType.DataType:
        vURL = ConcatenateString(vURL , "&tools=dt");
        break;
    }

    //build version 
    string VER_NUM = "5.0";
    vURL = ConcatenateString(vURL , ConcatenateString("&vsn=" , VER_NUM));         
    return vURL;
    }

    private string ConcatenateString(string expression1, string expression2)
    {
        return string.Concat(expression1 + expression2);
    }
```

But I am not happy with the one I am doing.

I am sure that there is definitely a best practice / better approach than this.

Kindly help me out in guiding for the same.

Thanks

Comment: What are you not happy with? What do you thing the deficiencies are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Never** build urls using strings, string builders, string concatenations.

You could start by defining a custom collection which will take care of properly URL encoding any value being added to it:

```
public class HttpNameValueCollection : NameValueCollection
{
    public override void Add(string name, string value)
    {
        base.Add(name, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value));
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("&", Keys.Cast<string>().Select(
            key => string.Format("{0}={1}", key, this[key])));
    }
}
```

And then simply:

```
public string BuildURLAndNavigate()
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://some.com/nav/somepage.asp");
    var values = new HttpNameValueCollection();
    values.Add("app", "myapp");

    switch (codeType)
    {
        case CodeType.Series:
            values.Add("tools", "ser");
            break;
        case CodeType.DataType:
            values.Add("tools", "dt");
            break;
    }

    // You could even do things like this without breaking your urls
    values.Add("p", "http://www.example.com?p1=v1&p2=v2");


    string VER_NUM = "5.0";
    values.Add("vsn", VER_NUM);
    uriBuilder.Query = values.ToString();
    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Why never use concatenation?  He is not concatenating user-inputted values into his URL.  He is only concatenating constant values.  So there is no chance of any form of injection attack.  While I really like this code example and could see it's usefulness in many cases (and I intend to steal it for my own personal use :) in this case it really feels like pushing a thumbtack with a sledgehammer.

Comment: I am always promoting best practices. Yes, in this case there cannot be an injection but maybe this is an oversimplified version of the real code. Maybe tomorrow there will be another developer that will come to the project and add some dynamic parameter value.

Comment: Also StackOverflow is a well referenced site. There are hundreds of developers constantly copy-pasting code snippets from the accepted answer without really understanding what it does (as they believe that if it worked in his case it will work in mine too) and they are surprised when they get night calls from angry customers that do not understand why the application truncates values they enter in the textbox :-)

Answer (score 8):

You could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx):

```
public string BuildURLAndNavigate(CodeType codeType) 
{  
    StringBuilder vURL = new StringBuilder();

    vURL.Append("http://some.com/nav"); 
    vURL.Append("/somepage.asp?app=myapp"); 

    //Build Code Type 
    switch (codeType) 
    { 
        case CodeType.Series: 
            vURL.Append("&tools=ser"); 
            break;  
        case CodeType.DataType: 
            vURL.Append("&tools=dt"); 
            break; 
    } 

    //build version  
    string VER_NUM = "5.0"; 
    vURL.AppendFormat("&vsn={0}", VER_NUM);          

    return vURL.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: string builder is overkill here.  For the amount of concatenation going on here you are likely going to see more of a perf hit then any boost.

Comment: Not necesarily. (keep one string  builder around). It also allows a more flexbile API with AppendFormat included ;)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is fine - it is simple and understandable. Anyone who reads the code can understand what you are doing.

In terms of performance - you are not doing much string manipulation, so unless you are building huge strings or doing this operation thousands of times a minute, you will not gain much by using StringBuilder. Before optimizing this code, test its performance. You will probably find that there are other bigger bottlenecks to work on first.

The only real comment I have is that your `ConcatenateString` function seems superfluous. It is not really adding anything to the code and all the call to it can simply be replaced by `string.Concat`. As mentioned in the answer from @abatishchev, you should be using `(str1, str2)` not `(str1 + str2)`, as that defeats the reason for the call.

Answer (score 2):

Like Saxon Druce said: You could use a [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx), but, depending on CodeType values, you could eliminate the switch too:

```
public string BuildURLAndNavigate(CodeType codeType) 
{  
    StringBuilder vURL = new StringBuilder();

    vURL.Append("http://some.com/nav"); 
    vURL.Append("/somepage.asp?app=myapp"); 

    //Build Code Type 
    vURL.Append(codeType == CodeType.Series ? "&tools=ser" : "&tools=dt");

    //build version  
    string VER_NUM = "5.0"; 
    vURL.AppendFormat("&vsn={0}", VER_NUM);          

    return vURL.ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: This might not be the same as eliminitating swicth depending on whether there are more than two values for the enum. It might be that there are values that just don't need to add anything to the url at all. You're probably right but figured it was worth mentioning explicitly.

Comment: Yes, I tried to allude to this case in the phrase "depending on CodeType values", but it really deserves to be more explicit, Chris. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
return string.Concat(expression1, expression2);
```

not

```
return string.Concat(expression1 + expression2);
```

Answer (score 2):

wouldn't the right way to do that be to use the Uri-class or the UriBuilder class?

for example the Uri ctor overload Uri(Uri, string):

```
public Uri(
   Uri baseUri,
   string relativeUri
);


Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://www.contoso.com");
Uri myUri = new Uri(baseUri, "catalog/shownew.htm");
Console.WriteLine(myUri.ToString());
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332624(v=VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, StringBuilder is the best solution here. You can find more information on MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx

StringBuilder contains very usefull methods:

StringBuilder.Append
Appends information to the end of the current StringBuilder.

StringBuilder.AppendFormat
Replaces a format specifier passed in a string with formatted text.

StringBuilder.Insert
Inserts a string or object into the specified index of the current StringBuilder.

StringBuilder.Remove
Removes a specified number of characters from the current StringBuilder.

StringBuilder.Replace
Replaces a specified character at a specified index.

Comment: URLs shouldn't be treated as plain strings i guess...
... the Uri class is made to handle relative references...

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally be inclined to just string.format something like that:

```
public string BuildURLAndNavigate(CodeType codeType)
{    
    string vURL = "http://some.com/nav/somepage.asp?app=myapp&tools={0}&vsn={1}"; 
    string codevalue = "";
    //Build Code Type
    switch (codeType)
    {
    case CodeType.Series:
        codevalue = "ser";
        break; 
    case CodeType.DataType:
        codevalue = "dt";
        break;
    }

    //build version 
    string version = "5.0";
    return string.Format(vURL, codevalue, version);
    }
}
```

Apologies if there are any mistakes in that, I wasn't in VS when writing it so there might be a few typos I didn't notice - you should get the idea though.

The reason I like this method is because you can immediately see what your url's overall form is which can make it a bit easier to understand roughly what the url being returned is.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep all variables at one place, could we use following solution

```
public string BuildURLAndNavigate(CodeType codeType) 
    {
        //code here - switch statement to calculate the codeValue

        //Anonymous type - To keep all variables at one place    
        var urlComponents = new {
                                server = "http://some.com/nav",
                                pageName="/somepage.asp?app=myapp",
                                codevalue = "", //Replace with the actual value calculated in switch statement
                                versionPart="&vsn=",
                                version = "5.0" 
                                };


        StringBuilder vURL = new StringBuilder();
        vURL.Append(urlComponents.server);
        vURL.Append(urlComponents.pageName);
        vURL.Append(urlComponents.codevalue);
        vURL.Append(urlComponents.versionPart);
        vURL.Append(urlComponents.version);
        return vURL.ToString();

    }
```